# When an element with link or transition is clicked the page scroll to the top

Tags: javascript, css

I want to resolve these issues and i know that if one is solved, the others will be solved as well.

Note: this works fine in bowser.

Problems:

1. Navigation on mobile is not working.
2. When element with transition
   was clicked, the page scroll to the top.
3. When input is focused, the page scroll to the top.

Link to my [Nikola Tesla Tribute](https://codepen.io/GrandMagus/pen/vYmNOGV) page

I also tried all of these stuff:

1. event.preventDefault()
2. pageYOffset to retain the scroll

```js
jQuery('*:not(.nocapture)').on('click', function(e){
    if (window.pageYOffset != undefined) {
      $(this).scrollTop(pageYOffset);
      //return [pageXOffset, pageYOffset];
    } else {
      var sx, sy, d = document,
          r = d.documentElement,
          b = d.body;
      sx = r.scrollLeft || b.scrollLeft || 0;
      sy = r.scrollTop || b.scrollTop || 0;
      $(this).scrollTop(pageYOffset);
      //return [sx, sy];
    }
  })
```

Comment: This is very clearly your homework assignment. And you have not provided us with a clear problem besides that you don't know how to do the assignment.

Comment: I already solved this problem. Thank you. 
I solved the problem using event.preventDefault(). 

Whenever I trigger a click action, I call first event.preventDefault() during the event.
item.addEventListener('change', e => {
     e.preventDefault();
     e.target.getElementsByClassName('element').add(class-holding-animation);
}

Comment: Also: overflow: hidden for body and html makes it work, remove the fixed element, set the scrolling of the main container.   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;